# How rewrite Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price for handle catalog_product_view?

Tags: html, magento, block

How to rewrite Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price only for handle catalog_product_view? This block haven't specific name in Layout.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="???">
        <block type="test/price" name="test.price />
    </reference>        
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: can you specify what you want to do?

Comment: I need rewrite _toHtml() in Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price for parse html for product page (add rich snippet attribute for html tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in magento the product type is defining the block that is used to render the price, it is a little bit tricky. Maybe this can work:

go to your favorite layout xml file and add this

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="catalog_product_price_template">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>simple</type><block>yourmodule/catalog_product_price</block><template>catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>virtual</type><block>yourmodule/catalog_product_price</block><template>catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>grouped</type><block>yourmodule/catalog_product_price</block><template>catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>downloadable</type><block>yourmodule/catalog_product_price</block><template>catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>configurable</type><block>yourmodule/catalog_product_price</block><template>catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>yourmodule/bundle_catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

iam not 100% sure that this will work but its maybe a start for you